# QRegEx to match a pure hue color

Tags: regex, validation, qregexp

I am creating a QLineEditor to manually input a color in hex format. I want to set a validator to check if the input color is a pure HUE color.

All hue colors follow this pattern, being X any hex character [from 0-9 or A-F]:

```
#FF00XX
#00FFXX
#00XXFF
#XX00FF
#XXFF00
#FFXX00
```

I managed to check for a correct HEX color value: `^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{6})$`, but I don't know how to extend the validator to accept only hue colors.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do I get it right you do not want to match `#FF0000` and `#FFFFFF`? The `XX` can't be `00` and `FF`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern you want is `^#(?:00(?:FFXX|XXFF)|FF(?:00XX|XX00)|XX(?:00FF|FF00))$`.

If you want `XX` to be any hex char, replace with `[a-fA-F0-9]{2}`. Then, the regex will look like

```js
^#(?:00(?:FF[a-fA-F0-9]{2}|[a-fA-F0-9]{2}FF)|FF(?:00[a-fA-F0-9]{2}|[a-fA-F0-9]{2}00)|[a-fA-F0-9]{2}(?:00FF|FF00))$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7Su0Cf/3).

If you do not want `XX` to match `00` and `FF`, replace `XX` with `(?![fF]{2}|00)[a-fA-F0-9]{2}`. Then, the regex will look like

```js
^#(?:00(?:FF(?![fF]{2}|00)[a-fA-F0-9]{2}|(?![fF]{2}|00)[a-fA-F0-9]{2}FF)|FF(?:00(?![fF]{2}|00)[a-fA-F0-9]{2}|(?![fF]{2}|00)[a-fA-F0-9]{2}00)|(?![fF]{2}|00)[a-fA-F0-9]{2}(?:00FF|FF00))$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7Su0Cf/4).

The `(?![fF]{2}|00)[a-fA-F0-9]{2}` part matches any two hex chars that are not equal to `FF` or `00` (case insensitive).

Comment: Your solution matches the one produced by running `perl -MRegexp::Assemble -E 'say Regexp::Assemble->new->add(@ARGV)->as_string' #FF00XX #00FFXX #00XXFF #XX00FF #XXFF00 #FFXX00`. Is that the tool you used to derive your answer from?

Comment: @tchrist No, this is something new to me, I just used a regex trie.

Comment: That makes good sense because a regex trie should produce an optimal branching structure for matching a set of fixed strings. I think you might enjoy seeing how the perl regex compiler generates `TRIE-EXACT` regex opcodes internally when fed your pattern by looking at the "debug output" from the regex compiler by typing this command: `perl -Mre=debug -ce '/^#(?:00(?:FFXX|XXFF)|FF(?:00XX|XX00)|XX(?:00FF|FF00))$/'`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to just use the pipe operator to cover all the six cases:

`00[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}FF|00FF[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}|FF00[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}|FF[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}00|[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}00FF|[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}FF00`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/noHt9m/1)

Obviously the pattern `[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}` is repeated several times. To remove redundancy, you can save it in a separate variable and use string formatting to substitute it and form the pattern as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

If there are just 6 cases you can write this cases using boolean OR (`|`)

`(?<=#00FF|#FF00)[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}(?=00FF|FF00)|(?<=#00)[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}(?=FF)|(?<=#FF)[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}(?=00)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/J5AIsH/1)